# Laravel - Undefined index in query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following array which I want to pass all values for "main_id" key to **whereNotIn** condition:

```
array:7 [
  0 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1354767"
  ]
  1 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1348470"
  ]
  2 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1300790"
  ]
  3 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1267286"
  ]
  4 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1260614"
  ]
  5 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1259115"
  ]
  6 => array:1 [
    "main_id" => "KWS1145684"
  ]
]
```

My code in controller is the following:

```
$search = $search->select("properties.prop_id as main_id")->get();
$searcharray = $search->toArray();
$prop_cnt = DB::table("offerdemandsmatchs")->whereNotIn('prop_id', $searcharray['main_id'])
            ->where('offerdemand_id', $o->id)
            ->get();
```

The error I get is:

```
ErrorException  : Undefined index: main_id
```

If I manually pass the array it works:

```
$prop_cnt = DB::table("offerdemandsmatchs")->whereNotIn('prop_id', ['KWS1354767', 'KWS1348470', 'KWS1300790'])
           ->where('offerdemand_id', $o->id)
           ->get();
```

I can't get values from array and if I pass the values as in the first statement it fails.
How can I pass array values as I'm doing it manually? Do I have to pass a collection?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pluck instead of select and then convert into an array.

Pluck method will create an array for you. check [method pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-pluck)

```
$prop_ids = $search->pluck('prop_id');
//$prop_ids = ['KWS1354767','KWS1348470'..];
$prop_cnt = DB::table("offerdemandsmatchs")->whereNotIn('prop_id', $prop_ids)
            ->where('offerdemand_id', $o->id)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you pass the wrong array to the statement.

What you must do is to use `array_column` on the search array:

```
DB::table("offerdemandsmatchs")
    ->whereNotIn('prop_id', array_column($searcharray, 'main_id'))
    ->where('offerdemand_id', $o->id)
    ->get();
```